# In Apollo Client, how can I inspect the loading state of the same query from different components using useLazyQuery?

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm using React functional components with hooks and Apollo Client 3. I can use useLazyQuery to inspect the loading state in the component I'm using it in, but is it possible to inspect the loading state of that same query in a separate component using Apollo's own API, i.e. without passing props or using React's context?

Answer (score 0):

No. The state that's exposed through Apollo's hooks is specific to the component where the hook is called (it uses `useRef` under the hood). Even the `data` property, which may be populated by Apollo's in-memory cache and may be changed when the cache changes, is still just component state.

That said, you can call the same query across multiple components in your app and it will only be fetched once from your server provided you use the default `fetchPolicy`. That should be the case whether you're using `useQuery` or `useLazyQuery`.

Comment: OK thank you. I guess I'll have to use another method to track loading state like putting the calling function for the lazy query and the result in a react context in a parent component.